# React Native: How to implement swipe action in GetStream ChannelList?

Tags: react-native, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I am new to RN and using GetStream, I need to implement something like this.

[image]

This is from their actual demo app tho I believe this is made with native since I tried searching but what I saw in their documentation is native implementation. I tried to check this [sample](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react-native/wiki/Cookbook-(2.x.x)#swipe-message-left-to-delete-and-right-to-reply-message-example-9) snippet but it seems to be incomplete.

As of now I only have the basic setup where I can display the channels.

```
 <View style={{ marginTop: 140 }}>
          <Chat client={chatClient}>
            <ChannelList
              // PreviewAvatar={CustomPreviewAvatar}
              // PreviewTitle={CustomPreviewTitle}
              filters={filters}
              options={options}
              onSelect={(channel) => {
                // channel.delete()
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(channel))
                // navigation.navigate('ChatRoom', {
                //     channel: channel,
                //     chatClient: chatClient,
                //     chatData: channel.data,
                // });
              }}
            />
          </Chat>
        </View>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Stream DevRel here )

Our cookbook wiki has been [deprecated](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react-native/wiki#-this-wiki-has-been-deprecated-and-will-not-be-maintained-here-onwards-), please refer to our [official documentation](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/reactnative/).

You can achieve the swipe functionality by doing something similar to what we've done in our Sample app, see [ChannelPreview](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react-native/blob/develop/examples/SampleApp/src/components/ChannelPreview.tsx#L71) component